# SQL поиск по букве в инициалах

Tags: sql, like

Всем привет,

Я новичок в SQL. ПО заданию нужно вывести название и автора тех книг, название которых состоит из двух и более слов, а инициалы автора содержат букву «С». Считать, что в названии слова отделяются друг от друга пробелами и не содержат знаков препинания, между фамилией автора и инициалами обязателен пробел, инициалы записываются без пробела в формате: буква, точка, буква, точка. Информацию отсортировать по названию книги в алфавитном порядке.

у меня есть такой запрос -

```sql
SELECT title, AUTHOR 
FROM book 
WHERE title LIKE "_% _.С." 
   or title LIKE "_% С._." 
ORDER BY title asc;
```

Подскажите, что я сделал не правильно?
Заранее спасибо!
Дмитрий

Comment: вам нужно два правила, одно к названию про пробелы, другое к автору про инициалы. вы же почему-то пихаете инициалы в название. И второе правило инициалов, очевидно, не корректное

Comment: Вопрос требует **точного** указания используемой СУБД. Ибо паттерн оператора LIKE допускает служебные символы подстановки, которые различаются в разных диалектах SQL. Впрочем, я бы вместо LIKE рекомендовал использовать функцию INSTR(), которая емнип не только существует в любой СУБД, но даже по типу/порядку параметров и типу результата не отличается.